# How does TFS choose which check-ins to associate with a build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Our builds generally have a mish mash of work items and commits associated with them and I cannot tell how TFS determines what to add. We are using TFS 2015 update 3 and TFVC.

When a build runs, it gets code from a location somewhere in the branching and folder of TFVC. Typically, something like "root\dev\src\component name" in this way we avoid getting all of the code in our repository and we have CI set up to run so that any changes in this folder will result in a CI build running.

We also run daily builds which run more tests and create a release package that is used by TFS Release Management. I would expect that any changes to code inside of the folder defined in setting up the repository for this build to be included in the associated change-sets of a build. I also expect that any changes checked-in outside of these branches would not be associated. But this is not the case. We see commits from across the entire project.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

I am not sure if this should go in the question or the answer but I have found some additional information, thanks to the hints provided in the answers below.

It appears that the source settings will take the common root between mapped folders of the repository settings, so if I have 2 folders $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/Claims.Services and $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/PSScripts  it will take the common root $/Relo/Dev/B1/src as the source settings and include any changes from that folder down within the build. Can anyone confirm this? Of course thats not what I want to have happen. In the History tab of the build definition if I looked at the diff I can see a field "defaultBranch" in the json which seems to be the value that controls this, is there any way to update this field directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS determines what changesets should be mapped to a build based on the Source Repository Mappings (Build vNext) in the build definition and the last successful build.

So, you will see a list of the changesets with files committed in the lowest common base of **any** of the mapped folders **including** all their descendents, since the latest successful build. Whenever you get a successful build (I hope that it happens more often than failing ones ;-)) the list will shorten and only show the last check-in.

Example mappings below will result in any changeset made to anything below $/Relo/Dev/B1/src (because it is the lowest common base):

- $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/Claims.Services
- $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/PSScripts

Similar it will pick up all the related work items to the above changesets.

This is what **should** happen. If you see something else, I would have a closer look at the Repository Mappings or Source Settings of the build definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "Source Settings"? Do you mean the Repository Mappings? I have 2 folders mapped $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/Claims.Services mapps to $(build.sourcesDirectory\Claims.Services and $/Relo/Dev/B1/src/PSScripts mapped to $(build.sourcesDirectory\PSSCripts, but I have change-sets that are associated with the build that include files that come from outside of these folders, none from inside.

Comment: Yes, Repository Mappings are called Source Settings in build XAML Builds (sorry, I am still on the old system) - I have updated the answer to include this name. Does your changesets by any chance contain files from a descendant of one of the mapped folders?

Comment: No, As I tried to explain above in editing the question, it appears that TFS Build will change the "Source Branch" or "defaultBranch" to the lowest common folder across your mapped repositories. In my example in the comments section the lowest common folder is "$/Relo/Dev/B1/src" Which is of course my root source code folder, so all changes between builds get included.

Comment: Sorry @Noel, I forgot about the common base across the mapped repositories. That one have also caught me wondering :-).

Answer (score 0):

@Noel - I guess you are using vNext build and not XAML builds. Or are you using a mix of XAML and vNext?

In general a scheduled TFS build will associate all changes which were not associated in the last successful run of the same build.

I suggest you check once again if the source folder locations are the same for CI build and Daily build?

Comment: We are using vNext builds.

Comment: @Noel - Are there are only two build definitions - 1 for CI and 1 for Daily?

Have you confirmed that under the Triggers section of the build definition the path is the same for both the build definitions?

Comment: There are no triggers currently set. I am running them manually. There are multiple definitions for this same solution, but I believe I have narrowed the problem down further as described above in the additional information I added in the question.

Comment: Okay. I will run through your scenario once.

You had mentioned that you have a CI build. CI build is where the trigger is set to "Continuous Integration".

Comment: I do have a CI build but that is not the build I am talking about. I am talking about a build with out any triggers, it runs manually